# passport.js deserialization ok, but authentication not working

Tags: express, passport.js

I have a working development version and even my testing version worked until recently. The authentication works sometimes, but mostly the authentication just fails with req.isAuthenticated().

server.js:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = PORTS[ENVIRONMENT];

var passport = require('passport');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var passportConfigs = require('./config/passport');
var routes = require('./routes.js');

// App setup
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

// configuration ===============================================================
/* open mongo connection */
require('./database/' + ENVIRONMENT + '.js');

/* === passport configs === */
passportConfigs(passport, ENVIRONMENT);

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan(morganEnv)); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({
   secret: '********' ,
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());   
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

passport serialize:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  userQueries.findID(id)
     .then(function(user) {

        var firebaseRef = firebaseRefMod(user, environment).ref;
        if(!firebaseRef) {
           throw new Error('problem with generating firebase reference, dunno why!');
        }
        console.log("UserFirst:", { userData: filterUserData( user ), FBRef: firebaseRef })
        done(null, { userData: filterUserData( user ), FBRef: firebaseRef } );
     }).then(null, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        done(err, null);
     });
});
```

routes:

```
app.post('/auth', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  console.log("req", req.user)
  res.status(200).send({ "authKey": authGenerator.createToken(authGenerator.types.NORMAL, req.user.userData) , "user": req.user.userData } );
});
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  console.log("userIn", req.isAuthenticated())
  // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
  errorInRestRequest(res, errorCodes.userNotAuthenticated, req.user);
  return false;
}
```

So basically if the authentication succeeds as it should, the isLoggedIn-function has access to user data from req.user. Even if the authentication does not success, the user is deserialized without problem every time verified by the "console.log("UserFirst:"... entry), but the req.user does not hold the data when it reaches in isLoggedIn-function.

Unfortunately my knowledge of passport and express middlewares are limited, so I'm puzzled as to where the data vanishes in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was caused by wrong node module versions. Do not have the specifics yet, but reverting several modules to older versions fixed the issue.

Comment: an unfortunate answer